# TCP missing data java

Tags: java, tcp

I got problem with sending data using TCP first file goes flawlessly but i cant read next one from Stream

**Server**

```
while (fileCount>=0) {
    fr=new FileInputStream(listOfFiles[fileCount]);
    fr.read(b,0,(int)listOfFiles[fileCount].length());

    outToClient.writeInt(listOfFiles[fileCount].getName().length());
    outToClient.writeChars(listOfFiles[fileCount].getName());
    outToClient.writeInt((int)listOfFiles[fileCount].length());
    outToClient.write(b);

    System.out.println("file send");
    fileCount--;
}
```

**Client**

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    int length = inFromServer.readInt();
    int j = 0;
    System.out.println(length);
    String filename = new String();

    while (j < length) {
        filename += inFromServer.readChar();
        j++;
    }

    System.out.println(filename);
    FileOutputStream fr = new FileOutputStream("wallets2/" + filename);
    int lengthfile = inFromServer.readInt();
    inFromServer.read(b, 0, lengthfile);
    fr.write(b, 0, lengthfile);
    System.out.println("file recived");
}
```

I use length to get size of name and then read that amount of chars next I get size of file and read file from stream. First one goes through but when I read 2nd length read 0;

Comment: `outToClient.write(b);` What is `b`? You need to make sure you only write file length bytes here: `outToClient.write(b, 0, listOfFiles[fileCount].length()`.

Comment: b is buffor where is store bytes of file.

Comment: Thanks is worked.

Comment: Ok. I'll write up an answer to close out the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you write the entire buffer `b` no matter what size the file is. For example if you declare:

```
byte [] b = new byte[1000];
```

And the file size is only 123 bytes, when you call

```
outToClient.write(b);
```

This will write all 1000 bytes to the socket, but you only want to write 123 bytes. You can change to:

```
outToClient.write(b, 0, listOfFiles[fileCount].length());
```

To ensure you only write 123 bytes. The 2nd parameter is the buffer start index and the 3rd one is the length.